# Cordova 3.6.0 remote url CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR

Tags: android, cordova

I am using `Cordova 2.9.0` Google said upgrade `Cordova`. I have started use `Cordova 3.6.4` 
I was simply opening remote URLs:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.loadUrl(getString(R.string.mainURL), 4000);
}
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
```

The application works with `Cordova 2.9.0` but it does not with `Cordova 3.6.4`.
Here is what `Cordova 3.6.4` returns:

`E/CordovaWebView﹕ CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!`

How can I open remote URL with Cordova webview?

Comment: what does that "R.string.mainURL" contains. 

<access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true" />" replace by <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />\

Comment: my main url is <string name="mainURL">http://www.google.com</string> . I tried your suggestion and it worked. thanks

Comment: @MohammedImranN please add your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true" />`

replace with

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```